# Azure storage 'Lease' - correct exception approach

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am developing NET Core web app and I am using blob to store some objects what could be modified during request. I had to prevent multiple paralel access to one object so I add 'lease' into my storage integration.
In prctice when I receive request, one object is fetched from blob with lease for some period. On the end of request this object is updated in storage and lease is removed - pretty simple.
But what is correct exception handling?
I am faicing agains the problem when some exception occured in the middle of request, lease is not released. I tried to implement release into dispose (in some class where I control fetching and leasing from blob). But this is not executed when unhandled exception is thrown.
Add try/catch/finally seems not clean for me. My question is do you know some best common approach how release lease on the end request? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Few questions: 1) How long do you think your code would need to process the request i.e. for how long do you need to acquire lease? 2) What is your current lease duration?

Comment: Hello, thank you for Your reply. Request is completed in order of milliseconds. In edge case it reach 2 seconds. So, lease I set to 15 seconds (possible minimum as far I know)

Comment: If you're setting lease for 15 seconds and if for some reason you fail to break the lease, it will automatically be released after 15 seconds. You should try to break the lease as soon as work is done but if it fails, you know that the lease would eventually be broken.

Comment: The problem is I can not wait 15 second. When clients call cause exc. in the middle of request he naturally try it immediately once again and again.. He is not waiting 15 seconds. But each next request is stoped because lease exists since first failed request. This is why I need to remove lease during first request.

Comment: Understood. Other possible solution is to send the lease id back to the client (in case there's an error in breaking the lease) and let the client send this lease id back with the request. If the lease id is present in the request, you should try to break the lease first using that lease id, acquire the new lease and then try to perform the operation. Not the most ideal solution but I think that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Unfortunately I can not extend client's payload. I would like to solve it by some kind of middleware for example. Or some general exc. handler in .NET -idk, I am only guessing

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. Maybe my description of the problem is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Per your description, I write a simple demo for you about lease and break lease, just try the code below:

```
using System;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;
using System.Threading;

namespace getSasTest.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class editBlob : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string get()
        {
            var connstr = "";
            var container = "";
            var blob = "";
            
            var blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(connstr,container).GetBlobClient(blob);

            var leaseClient = new BlobLeaseClient(blobClient);
            try
            {
                //auto break lease after 15s
                var duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15);
                leaseClient.Acquire(duration, null);

            }
            //if some error occurs, request ends here
            catch (Azure.RequestFailedException e)
            {
               
                if (e.ErrorCode.Equals("LeaseAlreadyPresent"))
                {
                    return "Blob is under process,it will take some time,please try again later";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "some other Azure request errors:"+ e.Message;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) { 
                    return "some other errors:" + e.Message;
            }

            //mock time consumption to process blob
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            //break relase first if process finishs in 15s.
            leaseClient.Break();

            return "Done";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. Unfortunately I cant see solution of my problem. I can not move responsibility on clients which use API I am working on. My requirements are simple: 1) deny multiple access to same blob in one time. 2) in case of any error release blob to be immediately available for next incommig request. App take lease and fetch blob into memory on the beginning of the request. Then object is modified by some BL and then as last step blob is updated and lease is removed.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on your requirements, can't you authorize a party/cron/event (register event/ttl handlers?) to break a lease when some weirdness (whatever that means for you) is detected. It looks like you are really worried on the "pattern" over correctness?.

This should complement the correctness.

In practice, an exception handling strategy should lead to sufficient actionable information.

For some, that means:

- E -> E - 1 (digest or no digest) -> E - 2 (digest or no digest) ..

such that:

- E - n: Exception, at a certain level of nesting
- digest: would you propagate this or digest and move forward?

Breaking the lease (essentially correctness of program) should not mean you hamper your version of the elegance.

Every service is usually a pair of services:

- service itself
- service clean-up handler 1 through n
- service edge case handler 1 through n
- primer for service
- so on...